# How to make the search field responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have used bootstrap navbar for the start, how do I make the search field dynamic as that of Stack Overflow? For now instead of expanding it contracts.

```
<template name="DashboardLayout">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-8" style="align-content: right;"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.."> </div>
        </div>

      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/6r842g4r/

Add a class name to your input search field...

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="align-content: right;"><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." class="alive"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alive {
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.expand {
  width: 350px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const input = document.querySelector('.alive');

input.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.className += ' expand';
});

input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    input.className = 'alive';
});
```